# How to properly match a folder / directory with trailing wildcards

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module

This is a fairly newbie URL Rewrite matching question.  I want to be able to match all URIs which follow the pattern and redirect all such matches to a single place.

The following URLs should match:

```
www.mydomain.com/foo/*
```

and

```
www.mydomain.com/foo
```

All the above should redirect to www.mydomain.com/xyz/abc/something.html

So, the following should match:

```
www.mydomain.com/foo
www.mydomain.com/foo/bar
www.mydomain.com/foo/bar/baz.html
```

And the following should *not* match:

```
www.mydomain.com/blah/foo
www.mydomain.com/bloo/foo/blee
www.mydomain.com/bling/foo/blurp/blomp.html
```

I (perhaps naively) set up this rule:

```
<rule name="Rule1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="foo/(.*)" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/xyz/abc/something.html" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

This rule is working correctly for

```
www.mydomain.com/foo/
www.mydomain.com/foo/bar
```

But it is not firing for

```
www.mydomain.com/foo (note missing trailing slash)
```

And it is falsely firing for

```
www.mydomain.com/anything/foo/
```

How can I ensure that the rule fires only for URIs which begin with /foo and also fires for URIs which begin with /foo and do not have a trailing slash?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule will do the job:

```
<match url="(^foo/(.*))|(^foo$)" />
```

This ^ will ensure it matches foo always.

This will match

```
www.mydomain.com/foo  (with missing trail)
www.mydomain.com/foo/ 
www.mydomain.com/foo/bar    
www.mydomain.com/foo/bar/baz.html
```

Won't match anything

```
www.mydomain.com/anything/foo/
```

Comment: This is also falsely matching

www.mydomain.com/anything/fooxxxxx

Thoughts?

Comment: Good catch. Updating here in a bit.

Comment: Perfect. It's now working as I would like. Many many thanks for your help. It is much appreciated.